# How to retrieve default repository branch using gitpython?

Tags: gitpython

While I do know how to get the current active branch, I do want to retrieve the **default repository branch** (as in master or main) using gitpython and I was not able to find any docs on that (even pdb was of not much help).

```
import git

repo = git.Repo(".", search_parent_directories=True)
repo.active_branch # <-- that is current branch
```